# Sphinx-build can not be recognized as internl or external command

Tags: python, windows, python-sphinx, easy-install

On Python 2.5, I installed sphinx using `easy_install` and it is available at the following location on Windows 7:

```
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\sphinx-1.0.8-py2.5.egg\sphinx
```

I wanted to convert a couple of `.rst` files to HTML. But whenever I do `sphinx-build` I encounter the following error:

```
'sphinx-build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sphinx-build` command should be installed in `C:\Python25\Scripts`. Either use the full path, `C:\Python25\Scripts\sphinx-build`, to call the command, or add that directory to your PATH.

Comment: In my case, it is in roaming folder: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts`